# using C to create a child and parent process

Tags: c, linux, compilation, fork

I am making the following code in C. I am writing a program that creates a new process using `fork` system call. Then I want to check which one is active and finally if it's a child process return the list of all the directories within that file, or if it's a parent wait for termination of the child process.

Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <iostream>


int main(){
  int pid = fork();
  if(pid < 0){
    printf(stderr, "Fork call failed! \n");
  }
  else if(pid == 0){
    printf("This process is the child from fork=%d\n", pid);
    printf("Thecurrent file inside the directory are:\n");
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(".");
    if (d) {
      while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
      }
      closedir(d);
    }
    exit(0);
  }
  else{
    printf("This process is the parent from fork=%d\n", pid);
    int stats;    
    //parent process waits for child to terminate
    waitpid(pid, &stats, 0);

    if(stats == 0){
      printf("This process is terminated.");
    }

    if(stats == 1){
      printf("This process is terminated and an error has occured.");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory  #include <iostream>
                    ^ compilation terminated.
```

If I remove `#include <iostream>`, I get:

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘struct _IO_FILE *’
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Using C++ libraries to write in C?

Comment: i AM SORRY DID i MAKE THAT MISTAKE BY USING A C++ LIBRARY HERE?

Comment: `iostream` doesn't exist in C

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I see, okiI willremove that but how do I make sure the next error wont happen?

Comment: How are you compiling this? You didn't tell.

Comment: like this: gcc 1_3.c, then later ./a.out

Comment: @S.N BTW, I rolled it back to show the original question (the actual question that is answered)

Comment: @水飲み鳥 alright np.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is in the first function call to `printf()`:

```
printf(stderr, "Fork call failed! \n");
```

It should actually be `fprintf()` instead:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Fork call failed! \n");
```

---

Also, don't forget to include:

- `unistd.h` for `fork()`.
- `sys/types.h` and `sys/wait.h` for `waitpid()`.
- `stdlib.h` for `exit()`.

and remove `#include <iostream>` since that is for C++.

Comment: 1_3.c:12:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fprintf’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
.

Comment: Did you just replace the 1st `printf()` by `fprintf()` ?

Comment: @S.N. you need to replace only the first printf with fprintf.

Comment: Yes, it's only the 1st one (i.e.: the one taking `stderr`).

Comment: @水飲み鳥 I think it should be written using a while loop to make sure the child process is terminated, because currently it doesnt do that. if I am correct!

Comment: Line 12 of the posted program does not have fprintf in it. You are compiling something else.

Comment: @n.m. can u check it again I posted the new program.

Comment: @S.N This new one seems to compile.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 it does compile but I am not sure if the parent actually waits for the termination of a child process.

Comment: It seems it does (i.e.: `waitpid()`), why do you say so?

Comment: @S.N. The compilation problem is solved. If you have another question, post another question.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 I think in never goes to any of my if statements in the last if. thats why I think thats the problem.

Comment: @S.N Both of your last if statements are mutually exclusive, i.e.: only one is executed.

Comment: @S.N Anyway, as n.m. already suggested, if you have other problems regarding the execution of the child/parent processes, consider creating a fresh new question.